# Move cursor to end of value on mobile for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
```

When the user enters 3 numbers, `()` is added to surround these 3 numbers:

```
var inp = $('#input');
inp.on('input', function (e) {
    var curchr = this.value.length;
    var curval = input.val();
    if (curchr == 3 && curval.indexOf('(') < 0 && curval.indexOf(')') < 0) {
        inp.val('(' + curval + ')' + " ");
    }
});
```

So if I type `123`, It becomes `(123)`.

It works fine on desktop, But on mobile the cursor place is not updated.
As if I enter `123`, It becomes `(123)` But the cursor place is `(12|3)` not `(123) |`.

`|` represents the cursor here.

I searched for a solution and tried:

```
this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
```

and:

```
inp.focus().val(inp.val());
```

But no success.

Comment: Auto format while typing causes a lot of issues

Answer (score 1):

You can check length from string;

```
$('#input').keyup(function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var which = e.keyCode;
   if(val.length == 3) {
     $(this).val('('+$(this).val()+')');
     if(which == 8) {
       $(this).val('');
     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you resolve your issue.

```js
var inp = $('#input');

inp.on('input', function (e) {
    var curchr = this.value.length;
    var curval = inp.val();
    if (curchr == 3 && curval.indexOf('(') < 0 && curval.indexOf(')') < 0) {
        inp.val('(' + curval + ')' + " ");
        var inpLength = inp.val().length;
        inp.focus();
        inp[0].setSelectionRange(inpLength, inpLength);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. I had one typo in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let telEl = document.querySelector('#phoneNum')

telEl.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  let val = e.target.value;
  e.target.value = val
    .replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d{1,3})(\d{1,4})?(\d{1,4})?/g, function(txt, f, s, t) {
      if (t) {
        return `(${f}) ${s}-${t}`
      } else if (s) {
        return `(${f}) ${s}`
      } else if (f) {
        return `(${f})`
      }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phoneNum" maxlength="14" />
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! @user_125 told that provided example works fine on a desktop, but the problem is on mobile side. It would be better to describe what causes the problem on a mobile device, than throwing completely different example without a comment.